# How do I add a animation to a scriptable object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a game and I want to make it so that when you create a scriptable object for a weapon or an item, you add it's respective animations too. The problem is that I just found out you can't add prefabs to scriptable object. What can I do?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why not use prefab?

Comment: My animation is a prefab

Comment: Why not just use the prefab but insist on using scriptable object?

Comment: For customizability. And I've anyway fixed it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So I've worked it out! instead of using animations, I just used animation clips. Turns out Unity allows me to use my animations as animation clips but not just normal animations in scriptable objects. I am now using them in the animation component which is sadly legacy so you have to set your animations to legacy.